# Child componenet not updating when parent component is updating its array in react

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am having a list of item in parent react component and in which i am added new item and updating items. Child component will receive the items in props and render it.

When parent state is getting updated , child component is not updating its value. 
Do i need to update the state in child component state in "componentWillReceiveProps" ? What is the correct way of doing it.

```
Code Example 
// parent component 
import React, { Component } from "react";
import TestList from '../controls/testlistview'

export default class TestView extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super();
        this.state = {
            items: []
        };
    }

    render() {
        return (<div>
            <button onClick={this.addItem.bind(this)}> Add item</button>
            <button onClick={this.changeFirstItemText.bind(this)}> Change item</button>
            <TestList items={this.state.items} index={index}/>
        </div>);
    }

    addItem() {
        var items = this.state.items.map(s=> s);

        items.push('new one');
        this.setState({
            items: items
        });
    }



    changeFirstItemText() {
        var items = this.state.items.map(s=> s);
        items[0] = "changed text";
        this.setState({
            items: items
        });
    }
}



//Child component
import React, { Component } from "react";

export default class TestList extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super();
        debugger;
        this.state = {
            rootNodes: props.items
        };
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
        debugger;
    }

    render() {
        var items = this.state.rootNodes.map((s) => {
            return <div>{s}</div>;
        });
        return <div>{items}</div>;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why does your child have its own state at all?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
render() {
        var items = this.state.rootNodes.map((s) => {
            return <div>{s}</div>;
        });
        return <div>{items}</div>;
    }
```

you get the items from props

```
render() {
        var items = this.props.items.map((s) => {
            return <div>{s}</div>;
        });
        return <div>{items}</div>;
    }
```

You don't have to assign props to TestList state again, otherwise you will need to do setState() again from TestList in order to trigger the render again. (which is not necesary step)

http://codepen.io/kossel/pen/ObQLoR

Answer (score 0):

In the TestList class you shouldn't assign the props to the Component's state - this is a surefire way to cause major issues in React, and is the cause of your issue here.  See [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40849656/react-props-are-updating-automatically/40851072#40851072) for why this is a bad idea.

If you change your TestItem to the following, then it should work fine.

```
export default class TestList extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super();
        debugger;
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
        debugger;
    }

    render() {
        var items = this.props.items.map((s) => {
            return <div>{s}</div>;
        });
        return <div>{items}</div>;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Reason is you are creating the ui element by the state of child component.
There are two ways of solving this issue:
1. update the state value in componentWillReceiveProps() funtion like this

```
 componentWillReceiveProps(newProps){
        this.setState({
            rootNodes: newProps.items
        });
}
```

2.Create the ui element directly from the props values like this-

```
render() {
    var uiItems = this.props.items.map((item) => {
        return <div>{item}</div>;
    });
    return (<div>{uiItems}</div>);
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  i need to manipulate props and creating state items, so first option works, but my question is , is that the correct way of doing it ?

Comment: both the ways are correct, state variable are used when you want to store some info of the component, in this case you are creating the fixed ui elements so the better way will be the 2nd one, Lets say you are creating some text field or any other ui that user can change then 1st option will be the better in that case.

Comment: in my real appliction its not just fixed UI thats why used state. thanks for the answer.

Comment: I would strongly recommend against option 1, for the reasons outlined in my answer.  React is all about having a single source of truth, and using props to generate state is apposite to this.

Comment: To back up my comment above, see the [SO React docs](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/reactjs/1816/state-in-react/15854/common-antipattern#t=201612072356249249932)

Comment: in this example parent is passing a prefix and child is appending a value to that, so no need to store url in state variable, only store the value that you want to append. But there are many cases where parent is passing some initial value to child component and in child component user can edit that, application on which currently i m working have many such scenarios. So in that case you have to store the values in state variable. I agree with you on the point single source of truth, and we should follow that also but for some cases we have to store data in state variables.

Comment: Just because the child needs to be able to update the value doesn't mean it needs to be in the child's state.  You need to also pass a function to the child via props that will update the state of the parent.  If this approach gets over complicated with props passing through multiple components, then that is the perfect argument for a state management library like redux or mobx.